# div does not cover even with background size cover

Tags: html, css, background-size

[The picture of how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2HbMg.jpg)

I tried to make the divs width over the whole screen, but there is a little cutout where the body is in sight and I don't wanna see the body anymore

**The body**

```
body {
background-image: url(bild/backgrund-index.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-color: transparent;
font-family: minFont;
background-size:cover;
background-attachment: fixed;
```

}

**The css of the two divs shown in the picture**

```
.lean {
 height:1000px;
 background-image:url(bild/forstaSidaForklaringUtanText.png);
 font-family:'Segoe Script';
 font-size:200px; 
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 Width:100%; 
 background-size: cover;
 background-clip: border-box;
 text-align:center; 
 clear:both;
 color:rgba(255,255,255,1);

 top:25%;   
  }

.nice {


background-image:url(bild/chiligryta.jpg);
font-family: minFont;
font-size:16px;

min-height: 1000px;
top:20%;


background-attachment: fixed;
background-size: cover;
background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;

}
```

Comment: `body{padding: 0; margin: 0;}`

Comment: Did that fix your problem?

Comment: yes, it did. Thx again